# Windows 7 64bit keyboard issues

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, 64-bit

I have a Pavilion dv4-2153cl notebook running Windows 7 64bit Enterprise edition. (The processor is an intel i3) This morning I started to notice some really strange behavior in how it handled its built-in keyboard. At random intervals there will be a long delay in key presses, to which some keys will never show and other keys will continue to repeat until you hit the backspace. Other keys get mapped incorrectly to other keys.

If I hook up an external keyboard the problem does not appear.

Before I reformat the machine and do a fresh install, I thought I would check here to see if anyone has experienced this same issue and if so, how did you fix it?

[Update] After doing a fresh install of Windows 7, the problem is still occurs, thus ruling out any virus or spy/mal-ware.

[Edit] Added processor type and model number

Comment: It would have been nice if you had given us more information over the last week to help you resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly a malfunctioning keyboard. Consider contacting HP for a keyboard replacement. This will be covered if the laptop is still under warranty. Most laptop keyboards are $45-$100 USD and can be replaced with ease.

Comment: What JW said. You can download a Live CD for one of those *other* operating systems and boot from that CD to test a completely separate OS/boot process if you want, but I suspect your problem is the physical keyboard itself. If the problem persists after booting another OS on CD then you can fairly well rule out software issues.